# Open API Maven Plugin: how to generate code for File upload

Tags: java, feign, openapi-generator

I'm unable to generate an open api generated Feign client for File upload.

This is a snippet of the open api *requestBodies* component I'm trying to use to upload an array of files

```
requestBodies:
    FilesRequestBody:
      description: Array of files
      content:
        multipart/form-data:
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              files:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: file
```

my pom file contains the following plugin settings

```
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-feign-client</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.build.directory}/contract/api.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <language>java</language>
                            <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>
                            <library>feign</library>
                            <typeMappings>
                                <mapping>file=File</mapping>
                            </typeMappings>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
```

notice the ***typeMappings*** configuration - which doesn't work.

Ideally I'd like a generated Feign client which looks something like..

```
import feign.Param;
import feign.RequestLine;

import java.io.File;

public interface ImagesApi {

    @RequestLine("POST /api/images")
    @Headers({
            "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
            "Accept: application/json"
    })
    List<Image> uploadImages(@Param("config") List<File> files);

}
```

However, this is generated, which obviously doesn't compile

```
    @RequestLine("POST /api/images")
    @Headers({
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
        "Accept: application/json",
    })
    List<Image> uploadImages(UNKNOWN_BASE_TYPE UNKNOWN_BASE_TYPE);
```

any ideas how I can make the maven plugin use a Java Type like java.io.File ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in OpenAPI Generator v6.0.0 release: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/releases/tag/v6.0.0. Please give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is be a bug in the openapi generator. It can't handle

```
     $ref '#/components/requestBodies/FilesRequestBody'
```

So to make it work, don't use a components reference.. inline the request body

```
  /api/images:
    post:
      tags:
        - image
      summary: uploadImage
      operationId: uploadImage
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                file_list:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: string
                    format: binary
      responses:
        "201":
          $ref: '#/components/responses/ImagesResponse'
        default:
          $ref: '#/components/responses/ErrorResponse'
```

Comment: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/7922